# Getting reference of a tableView in a child container view in the master view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have a `UIViewController` that has a comment `UITextView` in the bottom. And on the top part of the view controller i have a `UIView` "A content view" that has a comments `UITableView` being served in it.

What i need is a reference for the tableView found in the content `UIView` in the master `UIViewController` so i would be able to reload the tableView after posting a comment.

Tried several things with no luck. Always `nil`. Can anybody help me with a sample.

[image]

Comment: Get rid of the content `UIView` and just put the table view in its place but if the table view is an instance property of the view controller, it wouldn't matter what view it's in.

Comment: @Mia thats is true i really cannot remember why i did it this way yesterday :?

Comment: You should try with delegate.

Comment: @Jacky i tried with delegate i got nil. Maybe i did it wrong.

Comment: Can you post some code. ?

Comment: How you set delegate and used it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped) // for example

}
```

Now your table view is accessible from anywhere in the view controller.